# CSS id issues with styles

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to get each individual span element to be hidden for some jQuery effects but, the `display:none;` style is not affecting any of the ids associated with it

```
#a1, #a3, #a4, #a5, #a6, #a7, #a8, #a9, #a10, #a11, #a12, #a13, #14,
#a15, #16, #a17, #a18, #a19, #a20, #a21, #a22, #a23, #a24, #a25, #a26,
#a27, #a28, #a29, #a30, #a31, #a32, #a33
{
    display:none;
}
```

Comment: looks like you have other styles which override these styles.

Comment: can you share a fiddle ?

Comment: You can put these in one id.

Comment: Can you create a fiddle like @janakshah said? It will help uss see the problem to help diagnose it. Also if they are the same element use a container prefix on the elm like: `#container p { display: hidden }` all `<p>` tags would be hidden inside `<div id="container">`

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=JcqzEGQSr4

Comment: Not sure if its my phone, but that fiddle doesn't load.

Comment: @Mr.Latta you still left an id of `#16` (instead of `#a16`), here it is http://jsfiddle.net/viphalongpro/aWPLB/ @JeyTheva pointed out your problem correctly, you should accept her answer.

Comment: For future reference, you could just use `#list span {display: none;}`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

class name or ID name can't start with a number check this. **#14**. If you change this as **#a14** then this will work fine.

and same as **#16** also

Comment: you sharp eyes, I did not even notice the ids starting with number in there.

Comment: @KingKing cause this is not css , it is a maze :/

Comment: Thanks & check the **#16** also.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
#a1,#a2,#a3{display:none;}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<h1>This is a visible heading</h1>
<h1 id="a1">This is a hidden heading</h1>
<h1 id="a2">This is a hidden heading</h1>
<h1 id="a3">This is a hidden heading</h1>

<p>Notice that the hidden heading does not take up space.</p>
</body>

</html>
```

**Dont Start an ID with a NUMBER**